# Censored regression with Poisson distribution

Tags: maximum-likelihood, poisson-distribution, censoring

I am trying to fit a Poisson distribution  for left censored data. Let $x_1,x_2,...x_n$ be the observations with the first $r$ observations being less than the threshold of $c$ and hence censored. The observations $r+1$ to $n$ are fully observed.
Then the likelihood function is:
$L(\lambda)=\prod_{i=1}^r F(x_i;\lambda)\prod_{i=r+1}^n f(x_i;\lambda)$, where $F(x_i;\lambda)$ is the cumulative distribution function.

1) I don't quite understand how the cumulative distribution function part works here. Is it, $F(x_j;\lambda)=P(X_j<=c)=\sum_{j=0}^c P(X_j=j)=\sum_{j=0}^c {\lambda^j e^{-\lambda}\over j!}$?
Should it be summed upto $c$?

So as an example, if there were only 3 observations with the first 2 being censored then is it that,
$L(\lambda)=F(x_1)*F(x_2)*f(x_3)=\sum_{j=0}^c {\lambda^j e^{-\lambda}\over j!}*\sum_{j=0}^c {\lambda^j e^{-\lambda}\over j!}* {\lambda^{x_3} e^{-\lambda}\over x_3!}$

2) If the parameter of the Poisson distribution was $X$~$Poisson(e^{-\lambda t})$ and I want to fit for data observed at time points $t=[0,1,2,3,4]$ and $X=[5000,3000,100,10,10]$ with observations less than 10 being censored, how should  this Likelihood function be changed?
Here, with time the parameter changes and I don't understand how to handle that.

Comment: Do you want the Poisson parameter (the mean) to be equal to $\exp(-\lambda t_i)$?  If so, your observation $X_1=5000$ for $t_1=0$ implying a mean of $\exp(-\lambda\cdot 0)=1$ would be extremely unlikely.

Comment: @JarleTufto I want the Poisson parameter to be $\exp(-\lambda t_i)$. To solve $t_1=0$ issue I will have to make the Poisson parameter to be $X$~Poisson $X_1 \exp(-\lambda t_i)$. I just wanted to know what the approach would be in this kind of a situation

Comment: [many similar posts](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=censori*+likeli*+answers%3A1+)  you can find answer somewhere there.